# AVAssetTrack's preferredTransform sometimes seems to be wrong. How can this be fixed?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I'm using `AVAssetExportSession` to export videos in an iOS app. To render the videos in their correct orientation, I'm using `AVAssetTrack`'s `preferredTransform`. For some source videos, this property seems to have a wrong value, and the video appears offset or completely black in the result. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `preferredTransform` is a `CGAffineTransform`. The properties `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are concatenations of reflection and rotation matrices, and the properties `tx` and `ty` describe a translation. In all cases that I observed with an incorrect `preferredTransform`, the reflection/rotation part appeared to be correct, and only the translation part contained wrong values. A reliable fix seems to be to inspect `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` (eight cases in total, each corresponding to a case in `UIImageOrientation`) and update `tx` and `ty` accordingly:

```swift
extension AVAssetTrack {
  var fixedPreferredTransform: CGAffineTransform {
    var t = preferredTransform
    switch(t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d) {
    case (1, 0, 0, 1):
      t.tx = 0
      t.ty = 0
    case (1, 0, 0, -1):
      t.tx = 0
      t.ty = naturalSize.height
    case (-1, 0, 0, 1):
      t.tx = naturalSize.width
      t.ty = 0
    case (-1, 0, 0, -1):
      t.tx = naturalSize.width
      t.ty = naturalSize.height
    case (0, -1, 1, 0):
      t.tx = 0
      t.ty = naturalSize.width
    case (0, 1, -1, 0):
      t.tx = naturalSize.height
      t.ty = 0
    case (0, 1, 1, 0):
      t.tx = 0
      t.ty = 0
    case (0, -1, -1, 0):
      t.tx = naturalSize.height
      t.ty = naturalSize.width
    default:
      break
    }
    return t
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem but it only seemed to appear recently with iOS 14. Before that, `preferredTransform` seemed to work correctly for years. Have we figured out how the incorrect translation is being created for the asset track? I'd like to file a bug with Apple but I don't have a reproducible test case.

Comment: I managed to reproduce it on iOS 14 as follows: Record a video in portrait orientation using the camera app. Then, crop the video frame to a smaller rect using the Photos app. The resulting video shows the incorrect preferredTransform. I don't understand the technical details, so I don't know if this is actually a bug in the Photos app or in `AVFoundation` (Is the `preferredTransform` part of the video file or is it created by `AVFoundation`, based on other video attributes?). I filed bug FB8762584 which has been labeled with "Potential fix identified".

Comment: Great test case @Theo. Thank you. We were able to reproduce the issue with those steps. In terms of `preferredTransform` being retrieved vs calculated, that's a good question. I'm not sure. For what it's worth, when our iOS code encounters video made with Android devices, we found that some of the needed translations in the `preferredTransform` could be zero and needed to be fixed in a similar way.

Comment: I've built on this answer to include handling of the buffer size and additional commenting/explanation above

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing something slightly more robust I think, I nullified the transform based on where it would end up:

```objectivec
auto naturalFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, naturalSize.width, naturalSize.height);
auto preferredFrame = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(naturalFrame, preferredTransform);
preferredTransform.tx -= preferredFrame.origin.x;
preferredTransform.ty -= preferredFrame.origin.y;
```

Note that you can't just apply the transform on `(0, 0)` since `CGRect.origin` takes into account things like flipping.

Answer (score 1):

Building on to Theo's excellent answer, I will share a couple other helpful "fixed" variables that I created in the same style as his example, which I believe you will need in order to correctly handle the data.

Also, in my case I found that the "preferred transform" in the right/left/rightMirrored/leftMirrored cases were actually reversed from what worked for me (ie: I had a rightMirrored case but when applying Theo's logic (which seemed correct mathematically) I ended up with an upside down image.  I think there is an error in the apple code whereby the preferredTransform shows the rotation that was done to the buffer while saving, rather than the rotation that should be done to restore it to upright.

Also note I am using a custom AVVideoCompositing where I apply the transform directly to the buffer, which may differ from what a built-in compositing option does.

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

extension AVAssetTrack {


// This is the current orientation of the buffer which sits in positive X and Y space.  eg:  For a leftMirrored representation of a portrait 1080w by 1920h image, the buffer has had its X-axis reversed and is rotated to the left, but is still sitting in the top right quadrant in the space of X(0->1920) and Y(0->1080).  This variable is used to calculate the required fixedPreferredTransform and fixedNaturalSize required to handle the buffer appropriately.
var fixedOrientation: UIImage.Orientation {
    
    /*
     // Here is a list of debug transforms showing what each of these terms means.  Useful to check the logic below.
     let id = CGAffineTransform.identity
     let mirror = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
     let up = id
     let left = id.concatenating(.init(rotationAngle: 1.0 * .pi / 2.0))
     let right = id.concatenating(.init(rotationAngle: -1.0 * .pi / 2.0))
     let down = id.concatenating(.init(rotationAngle: .pi))
     let upMirror = up.concatenating(mirror)
     let leftMirror = left.concatenating(mirror)
     let rightMirror = right.concatenating(mirror)
     let downMirror = down.concatenating(mirror)
     */
    
    switch (preferredTransform.a, preferredTransform.b, preferredTransform.c, preferredTransform.d) {
    case (0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0): return .left
    case (0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0): return .right
    case (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0): return .up
    case (-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0): return .down
    case (0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0): return .leftMirrored
    case (0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0): return .rightMirrored
    case (-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0): return .upMirrored
    case (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0): return .downMirrored
    default: return .up
    }
}

// When handling the buffer, after it has been unmirrored and set upright using the fixedPreferredTransform variable, it is important to note that the size of the upright buffer might be the transpose (swap X and Y) of the original unmodified buffer, so that subsequent code knows the proper size to deal with.
var fixedNaturalSize: CGSize {
    let naturalSize = naturalSize
    switch fixedOrientation {
    case .up: return naturalSize
    case .down: return naturalSize
    case .left: return .init(width: naturalSize.height, height: naturalSize.width)
    case .right: return .init(width: naturalSize.height, height: naturalSize.width)
    case .upMirrored: return naturalSize
    case .downMirrored: return naturalSize
    case .leftMirrored: return .init(width: naturalSize.height, height: naturalSize.width)
    case .rightMirrored: return .init(width: naturalSize.height, height: naturalSize.width)
    default: return naturalSize
    }
}

// This is the required transform to change the stored buffer (located as defined by the fixedOrientation variable) such that it is upright and un-mirrored, with origin at X,Y = 0,0 and extending into the positive X and Y space (ie: in the upper quadrant).
// Note that the built-in preferredTransform variable does not include shifting of the buffer into the top right quadrant, which is required for subsequent processing.
var fixedPreferredTransform: CGAffineTransform {
    var t = preferredTransform
    switch fixedOrientation {
    case .up:
        t.tx = 0
        t.ty = 0
    case .downMirrored:
        t.tx = 0
        t.ty = fixedNaturalSize.height
    case .upMirrored:
        t.tx = fixedNaturalSize.width
        t.ty = 0
    case .down:
        t.tx = fixedNaturalSize.width
        t.ty = fixedNaturalSize.height
    case .left:
        t = .init(a: 0, b: -1, c: 1, d: 0, tx: 0, ty: 0) // to REVERSE the left turn
        t.tx = 0
        t.ty = fixedNaturalSize.height
    case .right:
        t = .init(a: 0, b: 1, c: -1, d: 0, tx: 0, ty: 0) // to REVERSE the left turn
        t.tx = fixedNaturalSize.width
        t.ty = 0
    case .rightMirrored:
        t = .init(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) // to REVERSE the right turn
        t.tx = 0
        t.ty = 0
    case .leftMirrored:
        t = .init(0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0) // to REVERSE the right turn
        t.tx = fixedNaturalSize.width
        t.ty = fixedNaturalSize.height
    default:
        break
    }
    return t
}
}
```